# Why check "Create new baselines" when creating a new snapshot in RTC source control

Tags: version-control, rtc

When creating a new Snapshot what difference does checking "Create new baselines" make ?

If this is unchecked, a snapshot is created and all components in the snapshot are backed up and so created baselines ?

If this is checked then new baselines are created but they also seem to be created when "Create new baselines" is checked.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/58744/difference-between-snapshot-and-baseline)

> A snapshot is just a set of baselines (each baseline from a different component). It's what ClearCase would call a "composite baseline".
>
> You can snapshot the state of either a workspace or a stream, whichever you prefer. That will automatically create baselines when needed, i.e., when the current configuration of a component in that workspace/stream is not currently captured in a baseline

So, as mentioned in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/65489/baseline-snapshot-and-build-process)

> When I create a new snapshot, it only create new baselines in changed components, not in components have no changes.

I suspect checking in "Create new baselines" will force the creation of baselines for *all* components, including the ones which were already at baseline.

That enforces consistency in the name of the baselines included in the snapshot.

Update Jan. 2018, 3+ years later: [Dmitry Grigoryev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4350586/dmitry-grigoryev) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384374/why-check-create-new-baselines-when-creating-a-new-snapshot-in-rtc-source-cont/24384717?noredirect=1#comment83283701_24384717):

> the label on that checkbox is much more clear in newer releases now

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o57D.png]

Comment: The explanation makes it so much clearer... /end-sarcasm

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.